# UISplitViewController - update Master tableview from Detail

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, alamofire, uisplitviewcontroller

I have an iPad Master-Detail application which `DetailViewController` has a form to submit a POST request to an API.

In case of success, which is the proper way to update the master `tableView` with the object just created?

**DetailViewController POST method**:

```
    @IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: Any) {

    // Getting data from UITextFields 
    if let name = nameTextField.text, let parent = parentTextField.text, let email = emailTextField.text, let phoneString = phoneTextField.text, let period = periodSegmentedControl.titleForSegment(at: periodSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex){


        guard let phone = Int(phoneString) else { return }

        let parameters: Parameters = [
            "name": name,
            "parent": parent,
            "email": email,
            "phone": phone,
            "period" : period
        ]

        Alamofire.request(endpoint, method: .post, parameters: parameters)
            .responseJSON{ response in

                switch response.result {
                case .success:
                    print("Validation Successful")

                    //Here's where i should update Master tableView (?)

                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error)
                }

        }


    }
```

I've searched for similar answers in StackOverflow but didn't found anything that works.

Ps: Sorry for the bad code, just beginning with swift here.

Comment: either use a delegate, or getting it from self.splitViewController?.viewControllers

Comment: @koropok can you please show me an example using the viewControllers array to invoke a method to reload data in tableview (Master)? I’ve been trying for days but no success.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your master is an UIViewController with a table view...

```
class MasterViewController: UIViewController {

    func reloadMasterData() {

        // Do whatever updates to your tableView's datasource
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

    func updateMaster() {

        // Call this func on Alamofire request success
        guard let master = self.splitViewController.viewControllers.first as? MasterViewController else {
            return
        }

        master.reloadMasterData()
    }
}
```